# How do I validate Mobile no. in Bootstrap 4 using constraint validation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is the code that I have used to create a form.
Basically, I need to validate mobile number on the clients'-side using constraint validation. Also, the error message should be displayed at the time the user inputs data.
I have used mdboostrap.
The `oninput="check(this)"` calls the function.
I need the no. of digits to be equal to 10.
Here's a codepen for editing .

https://codepen.io/aditya-jangid/pen/PxwNRV.

```
function check(input) {

    }
```

I need to write the function as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a pattern attribute to get the no. of digits to be equal to 10

```
<input type="tel" pattern=".{10}" class="form-control" id="validationCustom08" placeholder="Mobile" oninput="check(this)" required>
```

On the snippet I added a function that helps validate the value of the phone input. I will still recomend you to use `pattern` atribute. But this is a work around.

```js
// Starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
  (function () {
   'use strict';
   window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        var tel = document.querySelector('input[type="tel"]');
        
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
     form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
      }
            if(!check(tel.value)){
              event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
              alert('error on phone')
            }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
     }, false);
    });
   }, false);


  })();

function check(input) {
  if(input.length != 10)
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
   margin: 5% auto;
   background-color: #FFF;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 4px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   padding: 20px;
   max-width: 600px;
  }

  body {
   background: url('http://www.baltana.com/files/wallpapers-5/Blue-Background-HQ-Desktop-Wallpaper-16270.jpg');
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Register</title>
 <!-- Font Awesome -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.9/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
       Looks good!
      </div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       This Field cannot be empty.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
       Looks good!
      </div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       This Field cannot be empty.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustomUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
       </div>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
        required>
       <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please choose a username.
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom03">Address</label>
      <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="Address" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       This field is required.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom04">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom04" placeholder="City" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       Please provide a valid city.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom05">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" placeholder="State" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       Please provide a valid state.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom06">Zip</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="validationCustom06" placeholder="Zip" oninput="checkzip(this)"
       required maxlength="6">
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       Please provide a valid zip.
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom07">Country Code</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="validationCustom07" required>
       <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India (+91)</option>
       <option disabled="disabled">Other Countries</option>
       <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">USA (+1)</option>
       <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK (+44)</option>
      </select>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       Please Select a valid option.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom08">Mobile</label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="validationCustom08" placeholder="Mobile" oninput="check(this)"
       required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
       Looks Good!.
      </div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       Please provide a valid number.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom09">Gender</label>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
       <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="male" name="gender" checked>
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="male">Male</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
       <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="female" name="gender">
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="female">Female</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom10">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="validationCustom10" placeholder="Password" required minlength="8"
       pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$">
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       Only numbers, Uppercase and Lowercase and Length greater than 8.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom11">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="validationCustom11" placeholder="Email" oninput="checkemail(this)"
       required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       Please Enter a valid email ID
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="form-check pl-0">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
       Agree to terms and conditions
      </label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
       You must agree before submitting.
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- JQuery -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.9/js/mdb.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It does work. But Validation in Javascript is more preferred. Thanks btw.

Comment: Works on my side. Let me see what I can do

Comment: [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api) This might help you better understand constraint validation API.

Comment: Yes I am a little familiar. I recommend you use the pattern attribute and use a custom message if you get a ``input.validity.patternMismatch``

Comment: The new snippet doesn't work as expected. I have to add the pattern attribute for it to work. I don't want to add the pattern attribute. I know it's easier to use the pattern attribute but a custom error won't' be shown.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly match a uk phone number then you need to amend the pattern to something a little more complex:

```
<input type="tel"  pattern="^\s*\(?(020[7,8]{1}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*$" class="form-control" id="Telephone"
                                    aria-describedby="telephoneHelp" placeholder="Enter telephone" required>
```